# Laravel validation request from

Tags: laravel, validation

I have laravel validation request form, like this:

```
public function rules()
{
    $id = $this->input('wlId');

    return [
        'id'          => ['sometimes ', 'integer'],
        'domain_name'   => ['required', 'string', 'unique:white_label,domain_name' . $id],
        'disabled'      => ['required', 'boolean']
    ];
}
```

I set id for ignore my entry during the unique check, but if id is't an integer but for example a string then I will get sql error from validator.

How can I stop validation if the id field fails validation?

Comment: because you specified that should be integer: `'id'  => ['sometimes ', 'integer'],`
That means that should be only integer, but if you want to be an integer you should use 'numeric'

Answer (score 1):

You are going to ignore a certain value while using `unique` validation rule.
Consider the following snippet;

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

// ...

public function rules() {
    $id = $this->input('wlId');

    return [
        'id' => ['sometimes ', 'integer'],
        'domain_name' => [
            'required',
            'string',
            Rule::unique('white_label', 'domain_name')->ignore($id)
        ],
        'disabled' => ['required', 'boolean']
    ];
}
```

For more details, see this link; https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique

Comment: It's the same like in my example. If no id field is passed you will get sql error. Since the validator will try to get the domain name from the white_label table by the id

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#stopping-on-first-validation-failure) you can use `bail` rule

Sometimes you may wish to stop running validation rules on an attribute after the first validation failure. To do so, assign the bail rule to the attribute

```
    $request->validate([
    'title' => 'bail|required|unique:posts|max:255',
    'body' => 'required',
    ]);
```

In this example, if the unique rule on the title attribute fails, the max rule will not be checked. Rules will be validated in the order they are assigned.

Comment: Bail to stop my validation of a certain field, but further validation will still go.
In your example. 
If the title field is not passed, then unique: posts will no longer be validated,
but the body field will still be validated.


I want the body field not to be validated in case of a failed title field validation